# Cannot change NA's in one variable according to conditions in other variables

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, data-wrangling

In one variable I have various NA's that I want to be removed depending on if there is information different from NA a few following variables (the options for the next variables are "Yes" and "No"

The variables are of a character type

```
A tibble: 6 x 7

dispone comp func_atrib ord_dia actas_jgl comp_actu comp_reu

1 NA N/A N/A No No NA N/A

2 NA Sí Sí No No Sí No

3 NA Sí No Sí Sí Sí No

4 NA No No No No NA N/A

5 NA Sí No No Sí Sí No

6 NA Sí Sí No No Sí No
```

I have tried to change the values from detecting yes or no and from detecting NA's

```
trans <- trans %>% mutate(dispone,
 ~ case_when("Sí" %in% c(across(comp:comp_reu)) ~ "Sí",
 "No" %in% c(across(comp:comp_reu)) ~ "Sí",
                             TRUE ~ .))
```

it says:

```
 x `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
```

I try again with rowwise:

```
 trans <- trans %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(dispone = case_when("Sí" %in% c(across(comp:comp_reu)) ~ "Sí", "No" %in% c(across(comp:comp_reu)) ~ "Sí",TRUE ~ .))
```

It says:

```
"Error in `mutate()`:! Problem while computing `dispone = case_when(...)`.
i The error occurred in row 1.
Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."
```

Another try:

```
trans <- trans %>%
           rowwise() %>% 
           mutate(dispone = case_when("Sí" %in% c_across(comp:comp_reu) ~ "Sí",
                             "No" %in% c_across(comp:comp_reu) ~ "Sí",
                             TRUE ~ .))
```

It says:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `dispone = case_when(...)`.
i The error occurred in row 1.
Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I have also tried it another way. By detecting that there are no NA's (instead of detecting if there is a "Yes" or a "No":

```
trans <- trans %>%
           mutate(dispone = case_when(!is.na(comp:comp_reu) ~ "Sí",
                 TRUE ~ .))
```

But it says:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `dispone = case_when(!is.na(comp:comp_reu) ~ "Sí", TRUE 
~ .)`.
Caused by error in `comp:comp_reu`:
! NA/NaN argument
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: Problem while computing `dispone = case_when(!is.na(comp:comp_reu) ~ "Sí", TRUE 
~ .)`.
i numerical expression has 968 elements: only the first used"
```

I have also tried with rowwise... but I can't manage.

```
  trans<- trans %>% 
           rowwise() %>% 
           mutate(dispone = case_when(!is.na %in% c_across(comp:comp_reu) ~ "Sí",
                             TRUE ~ .))
```

Comment: in your first code `... case_when("Sí" %in% c(across(comp:comp_reu))` Do you mean `c_across` instead `c(across...`

Comment: Thanks. When I write it as c_across, it says Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..2 = ~...`.
x `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I think I can imagine what you are trying to do. But I can't help without a reproducible example. I guess we should switch to something like: `trans %>% 
  mutate(across(comp:copm_reu), ~ case_when("Sí" %in% . ~ "Si",
                                            "No" %in% . ~ "Si",
                                            TRUE ~ .))`

Comment: I have copied part of the df in the answer section. The first column (the one with NA's),  is the one that has to be changed according to the values in the next columns

Comment: `"Sí" %in% .` doesn't make any sense. Do you mean `. == "Sí"`?

Comment: Otherwise, please provide an example of your data by copying and pasting the output of `dput(mydf)` , and the outcome that you are looking for.

Comment: You mean that I write it like that? 
transpa<- transpa%>%
  mutate(dispone_jgl, ~ case_when(. == "Sí" %in% c_across(comp:comp_reu) ~ "Sí",
                                  . == "No" %in% c_across(comp:comp_reu) ~ "Sí",
                                  TRUE ~ .))

Comment: structure(list(dispone = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    comp= c("N/A", "Sí", "Sí", "No", "Sí", "Sí"), func_atrib= c("N/A", 
    "Sí", "No", "No", "No", "Sí"), ord_dia = c("No", "No", 
    "Sí", "No", "No", "No"), actas = c("No", "No", "Sí", 
    "No", "Sí", "No"), comp_actu = c(NA, "Sí", "Sí", NA, 
    "Sí", "Sí"), comp_reu = c("N/A", "No", "No", "N/A", "No", 
    "No")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

Comment: What I want is to remove the NA's in the variable "dispone", depending on if there is something other than NA in the other variables. If there is something different thatn NA in the other variables, I want that the answer in "dispone" is "Sí" (yes)